# FOSUserBundle, symfony 2.1. How can I add a role to a user at registration?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I'm sure this is a simple question but I can't quite see or find the correct way to do it.

How do I add a role to a user when that user is created using the registration form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. I was on the right track :)

Override the registration form handler.

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md

Add

```
$user->addRole('ROLE_MYROLE');
```

before

```
parent::onSuccess()
```